# Updating table in SQL Server for asp.net mvc project but class definitions disappeared

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I updated the tables in SQL Server by changing a lot of the data types stored.  To update this change in my ASP.NET MVC project, I refreshed the database connection, updated the model from database in my `.edmx` model and transformed all T4 templates.

However, now all my class definitions for each table have disappeared. Is there a way to regenerate these `.cs` files?

Comment: How did you create these .cs documents the first time?

Comment: I didn't do it manually.  I've updated the tables before in MS SQL Server, and previous updates have not caused the definitions to be deleted.

Comment: So you generated them automatically, then.  Can you generate them automatically again?

Comment: Ideally, yes, but I was also hoping for insights on why they disappeared.

Comment: I'm not sure that's answerable, given the dearth of information in your question.  The way you regenerate the files is the same way you generated them in the first place.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to delete the tables from the model , checkin to version control ( if there is one) and the add them again